# Why am I only getting 1 number in my array and not 100?

Tags: c#

I can't figure out why I am only getting 1 number saved in my array.

I am using a for loop to store random numbers in an array and am only getting a single result when I have state it is an array of 100.

I will eventually be adding a bit to get the max value of the array, but I cannot figure this part out first. I am only getting a single result.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int[] randomArray = new int[100];

    Random randomNum = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.Length; i++)
    {
        randomArray[i] = randomNum.Next(0, 1000);

        Console.WriteLine(randomArray[i]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: is this just the `ReadLine` breaking the app-flow? try removing that `ReadLine`... or moving it *outside* the loop

Comment: Thank you everyone, I am new to this. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: best way of saying thank you on StackOverflow is to [mark the answer that helped you as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print all numbers of the array you need to remove the `ReadLine` method from your loop statement and put it just outside so the loop can iterate properly.

You can see the code below:

```
    int[] randomArray = new int[100];

    Random randomNum = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.Length; i++)
    {
        randomArray[i] = randomNum.Next(0, 1000);

        Console.WriteLine(randomArray[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Regards.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud. Thank you! I am new to this and have been so frustrated by this problem.